# Cleanest way to convert from generic to concrete type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, generics

I have a method

```
public Dto Convert<T>(T source)
{
   //todo here?
}
```

And i need to call the following methods from there based on T, will i have to do TypeOf and switch statement (trying to avoid that)?

```
public Dto Convert(Contact source) {}
public Dto Convert(Org source) {}
etc...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `dynamic`:

```
public Dto Convert<T>(T source)
{
   var resut = (Dto)Convert((dynamic)source);
}
```

It will perform method selection at runtime depending on actual `source` type. Will also fail when there is no suitable method with that name available.

But it seems to be something wrong with your design in general. Are you sure you're not trying to solve [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: i think i was falling into the XY problem a little bit. Had to look it up :) I have started using dynamic now and that seems to do the trick.